# Getting a Rack GemNotFound with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger, rack

This is my first attempt with a ruby stack. I'm stuck with the following error:

```
Could not find rack-1.6.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I've successfully installed the following components:

- ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- rvm 1.26.11
- ruby 2.1.6p336
- nginx 1.8

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

- bigdecimal (1.2.4)
- bundler (1.10.6)
- bundler-unload (1.0.2)
- executable-hooks (1.3.2)
- gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
- io-console (0.4.3)
- json (1.8.1)
- minitest (4.7.5)
- psych (2.0.5)
- rack (1.6.4)
- rack-protection (1.5.3)
- rake (10.1.0)
- rdoc (4.1.0)
- rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
- rvm (1.11.3.9)
- sinatra (1.4.6)
- test-unit (2.1.6.0)
- tilt (2.0.1)

*** Gemfile ***

```
gem 'sinatra', '1.4.6'
```

*** Gemfile.lock ***

```
GEM
    remote: https://rubygems.org/
    specs:
        rack (1.6.4)
        rack-protection (1.5.3)
            rack
        sinatra (1.4.6)
            rack (~> 1.4)
            rack-protection (~> 1.4)
            tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
        tilt (2.0.1)

PLATFORMS
    ruby

DEPENDENCIES
    sinatra (= 1.4.6)

BUNDLED WITH
    1.10.6
```

*** config.ru ***

```
require './app.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

*** app.rb ***

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    'hello world'
end
```

I'm using the default Nginx folder for the app. I was able to execute the following test in config.ru:

```
app = proc do |env|
    [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, ["hello world"]]
end
```

But as soon I try to switch to Sinatra I get the error above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem.

I followed the installation instruction here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/trusty/

But since I'm using rvm I had to change the passenger_ruby directive to point to the rvm wrapper: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.6/ruby

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
rack (1.6.4)
...
        sinatra (1.4.6)
            rack (~> 1.4)
```

You have a conflict in the rack version. you want both 1.6.4 and 1.4.x
How did rack 1.6.4 end up in the gemfile.lock?

Comment: I tried everything, even adding rack in my Gemfile. I'm guessing that I can remove it now since it's a Sinatra dependency.